# How to pause bash script from python script?

Tags: linux, subprocess

I want to pause bash script from python script, the steps look like this:

1. I start script writer.sh from python script reader.py.
2. When writer.sh outputs third line I want executing of this script to be paused using some command in `reader.py`.
3. I want to resume execution of writer.sh using some command in `reader.py`.

Here are those two scripts, the problem is that `writer.sh` doesn't pause when sleep command is executed in `reader.py`. So my question is, how can I pause `writer.sh` when it outputs string "third"? To be exact (this is my practical problem in my job) I want `writer.sh` to stop because `reader.py` stopped reading output of `writer.sh`.

`reader.py`:

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep

print 'One line at a time:'
proc = subprocess.Popen('./writer.sh', 
                        shell=False,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
try:                        
    for i in range(4):
        output = proc.stdout.readline()
        print output.rstrip()
        if i == 2:
            print "sleeping"
            sleep(200000000000000)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    remainder = proc.communicate()[0]
    print "remainder:"
    print remainder
```

`writer.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo first;
echo second;
echo third;
echo fourth;
echo fith;

touch end_file;
```

Related question is, will using pipes on Linux pause script1, if script1 outputs lines of text, e.g. `script1 | script2`, 
and script2 pauses after reading third line of input?

Answer (score 1):

To *pause* the bash script, you can send the `SIGSTOP` signal to the `PID`.

If you want it to *resume*, you can send the `SIGCONT` signal.

You can get the pid of the subprocess with `pid = proc.pid`.

See `man 7 signal`

Comment: How do I know when to send this signal? I want to send it when writer.sh outputed "third" string.

Comment: Don't you want to run the **SIGSTOP** just after `print "sleeping"` ?

Comment: No, I want to pause after statement "echo third;" was executed in writer.sh.

Comment: My practical problem from my job is, that I want writer.sh to stop because reader.py stopped reading output of writer.sh.